# CMake Can't find MSBuild.exe for VS 14 2015

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-2017

I'm building a new project using precompiled librairies in Visual Studio 14 2015 win64. 
So when i configure my project Cmake, i'm selecting this compiler, but get the error :

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
Failed to run MSBuild command:
MSBuild.exe
to get the value of VCTargetsPath:
Specified file is not found
```

Why Cmake isn't able to find the location of this compiler ?

I have visual studio community 2017, and installed the add-on for Visual Studio 14 2015 win64. I can already make my solution work by setting up my project with Visual Studio 15 2017 win64, then manually change to 2015.

What should i do for Cmake to do it directly with VS14 2015 compiler ?

Comment: This error occurs if msbuild.exe can no longer be found in the location where Visual Studio 14 was originally installed. It may be that the registry entries are corrupt.  Try running `cmake` in a VS development shell.  This way `msbuild.exe` will be found in `PATH` unless it has been deleted.

Comment: sorry to ask, but how ? ... i'm using Cmake GUI, and don't know how to open a vs shell and what line to type for cmake.

Answer (score 1):

The VS development shell is buried in the start menu (`Visual Studio 2017->Visual studio Tools->VC`) and there are several to choose from.

Then you can use the command line to run `cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64"`.

If this will work or not I'm not entirely sure because the generator will look for registry keys for "Visual Studio 14 2015" to determine the path to the correct `msbuild`.  But you don't have it installed because you are using `visual studio community 2017` which works entirely different.

So when `cmake` fails to find `msbuild` for `VS14` it'll default to whatever is in the path and that will be `msbuild` for `VS 2017`.

That's when you'll find out if the add-on is compatible with `cmake` `VS14` projects and tool-sets.

It may be that the add-on is simply the `VS14` tool-sets.  If that is the case you want to generate a `VS17` project and use the `-T` option to use the `VS14` tool-set.

Also Visual Studio and CMake refer to `msbuild` as the build tool.  The `-T` option is to choose the platform toolset which is the version of the compiler to use.